# Composer\Downloader\TransportException: The "drupal.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)

Tags: 8, composer

In Drupal 8.9.x, After composer cache-clear. I am getting this error [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "drupal.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found) .

I can't run the composer install or composer update.

I tried to remove the vendor folder & composer.lock files too.

Even i tried,

- composer config -g repo.packages composer https://packages.drupal.org
- tried composer diagnose and after that composer update -vvv
- composer config -g repositories.drupal composer
  https://packages.drupal.org/8
- composer config -g repositories.drupal composer
  https://www.drupal.org/packages.json
- composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org

But no luck.

is something wrong? before the composer cache clear it was working fine. it happens only on after composer cache clear. Any help appreciated.

```
    "repositories": [
            {
                "type": "composer",
                "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
            },
            .....
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The drupal package repository is https://packages.drupal.org/8, none other. it should appear, in most cases, alone as the only added repo in composer.json:

```json
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
```

But as you have done it, with a named key, it will be as follows, which should be fine:

```json
    "repositories": {
        "drupal": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
```

I think the problem you are experiencing is that by passing the `-g` flag to `composer`, you are setting the value globally (for all projects) but the project's own `composer.json` may have a differing, or a wrong, configuration.

Comment: Yes, i tried with named key. but, its shows  [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]                                  
  "./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON                     
  Parse error on line 17:
  ...         },        },        {                                 
  ---------------------^                                            
  Expected: 'STRING' - It appears you have an extra trailing comma

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I ran again the command   "composer config -g repo.packages composer https://packages.drupal.org/8"   now it's working fine.

Answer (score -1):

I ran this composer config command, then it works.

```
"composer config -g repo.packages composer https://packages.drupal.org/8"
```

Comment: Actually, I am not sure about composer cache-clear.  it's started working on after 20-24 hrs. don't know why. is something bitbucket related config?

Comment: Your answer will work only on the computer you executed that command.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I am not sure.